# What values have been excluded from an observable stream?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I need to create a function that can detect which values have been excluded from an observable stream (hot or cold) by a filtering pipe operator. The operator could be any from [this list](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/) (for example: debounce, throttle, filter, ...).

Note that I would expect that the values would **not** have been transformed in any way by the operator, just included or excluded from the output.

My function signature in typescript could look something like this:

```
function applyFilter<T>(
    source: Observable<T>,
    operator: (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T>,
    ejectedValues: Observer<T>
): Observable<T> {
    // ...    
}
```

A usage scenario would look like this:

```
let source = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
let observer = Rx.Subject<int>();

let output = applyFilter<T>(source, filter((x) => x % 2 === 0), observer);
```

In this case `output` would emit `2 , 4` and `observer` would emit `1, 3, 5`.

PS. Note that this would need to work for hot observables too.

Comment: Can you share an example use case where you might need this behaviour for?

Comment: The code that dispatched the value in the observable needs to know if it has been processed or ignored by the pipe so that it can report success accordingly.

Comment: I am not overly familiar with rxjs but shoudn't this be a reduce rather than a filter operation?

Comment: @ShyamBabu Reduce is a transformation operator. The operation is variable, so it could be: debounce, throttle, filter, take, skip... etc.

Comment: This seems to be similar to what you are looking for https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html ?

Comment: @ShyamBabu Thanks, but this would only really apply to the predicate for the filter operator and would not apply for take, skip, throttle, etc...